# converting annotation from .xml to yolov5

Tags: xml, label, detection, yolov5

i have used rolabellmg to create annotations and i have over 300 xml files. I did run a detector and had some results. Now i want to run a YOLOV5 detector and more specific to import my data and annotation to roboflow so i can have some results and in the end compare them. My problem is that roboflow does not accept these .xml files and i have to convert them into yolo. I have tried some .py that do the conversion but i am havind some difficulties. More specific the .xml file i have is this type: `<size><width>1920</width><height>1080</height><depth>3<cx>738.106</cx><cy>425.2821</cy><w>17.1708</w><h>36.5781</h><angle>2.751593</angle>`

So i tried [xml2yolo](https://gist.github.com/wfng92/c77c822dad23b919548049d21d4abbb8) but i have to make some changes this is where i want your help.

Comment: Where are the missing closing tags in your xml file?